# How do you define paths in application?

Tags: php, config, path, include-path

I'm using global constants, like this:

```
/project
    /application
        bootstrap.php
    /public
        index.php
```

index.php

- defines PUBLIC_PATH and APPLICATION_PATH
- calls APPLICATION_PATH . bootstrap.php

bootstrap.php

- defines LIBRARY_PATH, MODULES_PATH, TEMP_PATH, CONFIG_PATH, ...
- does real work

Also i want to ask if there is better way to do this?

Comment: Why did this question become a community wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean your application is not public? Anyway, normally I just define a `ROOT` constant in my front controller (usually `index.php`) like this:

```
define('ROOT', str_replace('\\', '/', __DIR__));
```

Or on older versions of PHP where `__DIR__` is not available:

```
define('ROOT', str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(__FILE__)));
```

Since the inner structure never changes I just do something like:

```
include(ROOT . '/application/libraries/Email.php');
```

Instead of:

```
define('LIBRARY_PATH', ROOT . '/application/libraries');
include(LIBRARY_PATH . '/Email.php');
```

Less pollution. =)

Comment: In my case PUBLIC_PATH is the same as you described:
str_replace('\\', '/', `__DIR__`)
application dir is intended to be outside web root (security measure) so it needs additional constant: APPLICATION_PATH

Comment: @Hemaulo: Not really... You can use `/..` with the your `ROOT` constant.

Answer (score 1):

According to your directory tree:

This is the one I would use to LOAD PHP script, basically you can place it in index.php or in bootstrap.php

```
define("PROJECT_DISK_PATH", str_replace('\\', '/', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/');
/*
Server variables $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILE_NAME'] are both USELESS to 
accomplish this task because they both return the currently executed script and not this included file path.
*/
```

Then in your PHP script you do:

```
include(PROJECT_DISK_PATH . 'path/to/your/script/somescript.php')
```

And these are the ones I would use to LOAD JS/CSS script IN PAGES:

```
define("PROJECT_DOCROOT_PATH", '/' . substr(PROJECT_DISK_PATH, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/')));
define("PROJECT_HTTP_PATH", "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . JPL_DOCROOT_PATH);
```

So in your page you can do:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo PROJECT_DOCROOT_PATH; ?>path/to/your/script/somescript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am going for absolute path when possible, using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
When impossible, I use relative paths, much like as Alix does.